# syntax for unsyntax in syntax-parse

Tags: racket

can someone point me to how I can write this in syntax-parse/case?

`` [(list e ...) #`(list #,(f #'e) ...)] ``

basically I'd like each element in the list to be processed individually by `f` in unsyntax. I don't think the above is the right syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unsyntax-splicing` (which can be abbreviated as `#,@`) to embed result of list returning expression as individual elements of outer list. Then you can use `map` procedure to apply `f` over all elements of list returned by `(syntax->list #'(e ...))` expression. In the end it will look like this:

```
#`(list #,@(map f (syntax->list #'(e ...))))
```